# Eclipse: Spring Boot and Static Web Project

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

I have two projects - one named core and other named ui. In core project there is a `Spring Boot` application starter (Tomcat). In ui project there is an `AngularJS` web application (static web project in Eclipse). I'm running web application using `Run -> Run As -> Java Application` and I want Eclipse to set the content of ui project into core project's classpath or somewhere else so Spring Boot will serve it. Was trying to add ui project's folder to classpath in Run Configurations - not helping.

The structure is:

[image]

SampleWebStaticApplication.java

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @ComponentScan
 public class SampleWebStaticApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleWebStaticApplication.class);

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @PostConstruct
   public void initApplication() throws IOException {
     if (env.getActiveProfiles().length == 0) {
       log.warn("No Spring profile configured, running with default configuration");
     } else {
       log.info("Running with Spring profile(s) : {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
     }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SampleWebStaticApplication.class);
     app.setShowBanner(false);
     // init
     app.run(args);
   }

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
     return application.showBanner(false).sources(SampleWebStaticApplication.class);
   }
 }
```

WebConfiguration.java

```
 @Configuration
 public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ServletContextInitializer {

   private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebConfiguration.class);

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
     log.info("Web application configuration, using profiles: {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
     // init
     log.info("Web application fully configured");
   }
 }
```

Core project Build path:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Also `Spring Boot` application do not use my `application.yml` (ex. I can't change Tomcat's port). Thank you in advance.

P.S. Can't use Maven :(

Comment: What does your build file look like? I strongly suspect that your UI project has not been configured correctly to be included in the resources

Comment: @geoand Added some additional info

Comment: I'm not an Eclipse user plus I have never used Spring Boot without Maven/Gradle so unfortunately I can't be of any further assistance